# rollbackOnError option must be true on a production org

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I have followed the same process i always do;

```
sfdx force:source:convert -d ./package
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d ./package -w 100
```

I have only started getting this error in the last day. Even when i try to set the rollback on error with "-e true" it still throws the same error.

I cant see to have it deploy correctly... currently having to deploy to a sandbox and use changesets to prod(for the love of god please help)!!!

Comment: From [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm) The parameter --rollbackonerror has been deprecated and will be removed in v42.0 or later.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of cli?

Comment: Had this happen today.  My sfdx-cli is installed with npm.  Used an `npm install -g sfdx-cli` command and it works again.

Answer (score 1):

Yep figured it out. I tried running an update previously but that didn't resolve. I uninstalled by using these commands;
rm -rf /usr/local/sfdx
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sfdx
rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx ~/.config/sfdx ~/.cache/sfdx

Then reinstalled using brew cask install sfdx and the issue is no longer around. Thanks to those that commented.